# Local css file won't load with relative, absolute, or absolute with file:/// prefix in simple html page

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple html page on my local computer. I have two files - index.html, and styles.css; both which reside in the same directory.

file:///D:/Programming/Playground/Canvas/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="file:///D:/Programming/Playground/Canvas/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

file:///D:/Programming/Playground/Canvas/styles.css

```
body {
  background: #222222;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

I've attempted loading the html file in firefox, chrome, and IE - none of them load the css file.  It does not show up under the network tab in firefox, although I've verified I can manually navigate to the css file. There are no other errors in the console.  Any idea why this doesn't work?

I verified that both files are saved as UTF-8 and have also tried opening the browsers in administrator mode to no avail.

Edit: Noting that I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Dumb question - have you checked file ownership/permissions?

Comment: Administrator already had full privileges on both files and I tried loading the browser in administrator mode. But for shits and giggles I gave universal access and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried moving both files to a different directory or drive?  Just spitballing here, obviously, but given what you've provided there's no reason for any of the paths you've tried to not work

Comment: As a work around, I uploaded the stylesheet through this style editor in the firefox developer tools.  They load just fine using this method but I'd still like to know why an html file on a local drive can't load a css file from the same local drive assuming permissions are in order.

Comment: No idea.  Outside of the obvious (spelling error, syntax error, permission/ownership error), it should work.  Especially since you can open the CSS file in an editor, which suggests the file itself isn't corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, which is why it's so easy to overlook. **Your `link` tag needs an `href` attribute instead of a `src` attribute.** (Also, you don't need `type`, especially if you're using HTML5, which you seem to be, and you don't need the closing tag either.)

```html
<link href="file:///D:/Programming/Playground/Canvas/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

See [MDN for `link` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Attributes).

Comment: Wow ... that's pretty embarrassing.  I practically deconstructed my computer one piece of hardware at a time to figure out why it wasn't working when the answer was right in front of my face. Would you believe me if I said I started writing html 24 years ago? Haha, perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: Haha! I'm a bit shy of that, but I hear you. I don't even think `href` instead of `src` makes much sense (e.g., script uses `src`). I was surprised my IDE didn't complain. But when it wouldn't do the simple-case relative URL I figured it was a small typo or something. Anyway, happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  background: #222222;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

Edited! This work for me.

Comment: I've tried both styles.css and ./styles.css - neither work.

Comment: Try now with this @ThinkingInBits